# Overriden clean() function in form.py doesn't work in views.py while authentication in Django

Tags: django, authentication

I am practicing authentication features with Django.

It works without assigning cleaned_data to `super().clean()` in the clean() function, but I don't know if it's properly working, so to check which part I am encountering an error, I wrote the `print('not valid')` in file *views.py* and it's printed in the terminal. It seems that it doesn't go to the next step at the `form.is_valid():` part.

Which part should I change to go further at the `is_valid()` part?

I tried print('not valid') with `print(form.errors.as_data)` in the same line. It displays `{'email': ['Custom user with this Email address already exists.']}`

#### File *form.py*

```py
class AuthenticationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['email', 'password']

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(AuthenticationForm, self).clean()
        email    = cleaned_data.get('email')
        password = cleaned_data.get('password')
        if not authenticate(email=email, password=password):
            print('not authenticated')
            raise forms.ValidationError("It's invalid.")
        return cleaned_data
```

#### File *views.py*

```py
def login_view(request):
    form = AuthenticationForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email       = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            password    = form.cleaned_data.get('password')

            user        = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('blogs:home')
            else:
                return redirect('accounts:login')
        else:
            print('not vailid')

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', context)
```

Comment: What err you have got? Please add the complete error traceback to the question

Comment: no error comes with it , it's just not working.. I added one more print(form.errors.as_data)

Answer (score 0):

Your authentication form should *not* be inherited from `ModelForm`. Every time someone tries to authenticate, the default `save()` method of `ModelForm` will try to create a new user with the given email address. That is why you see the error `Custom user with this Email address already exists.`.

Instead, inherit your form from `django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm`:

```
from django.contrib.auth import forms

class AuthenticationForm(forms.AuthenticationForm):
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(AuthenticationForm, self).clean()
        email    = cleaned_data.get('email')
        password = cleaned_data.get('password')
        if not authenticate(email=email, password=password):
            print('not authenticated')
            raise forms.ValidationError("It's invalid.")
        return cleaned_data
```

Note that the Django's [default auth views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#all-authentication-views) will handle all of this for you, so in practice you should never need to authenticate manually.

Comment: tried that way but it didn't give any error nor go to next step,
I just deleted super().clean() line then it worked fine but still don't know how this works..